# How to check if a process has disk I/O requests in flight?

Tags: linux, process, io

I am wondering how to check if a process has some ongoing disk I/O operations. I tried to use Netlink to acquire [blkio_delay_total](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/accounting/taskstats-struct.txt), which is the cumulative delay of this process waiting for synchronous block I/O to complete. However, `blkio_delay_total` is only updated when disk I/O requests are finished. If disk I/O requests are being processed, it does not change and I cannot determine whether some request is still on the flight. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Ongoing is a tricky question. If my I/O is accepted by the Linux page cache from the process' perspective that I/O is now complete and is no longer ongoing. Perhaps a global view like that given by `iostat` is enough for you? I'm afraid your question is too vague to give a good answer - sorry!